# Why is HTML5 (or any HTML) a recommendation, not a specification?

Tags: html, specifications

The title of the question says it all. Is it a recommendation because browsers are free to do whatever they want anyway, i.e., they don't have to implement the recommendation and still allowed to call themselves HTML5 compliant or something like that?

I would assume that if this were a specification, that would imply that W3C or the WHATWG has authority to not allow some vendor to claim they are compliant.

Is that understanding correct? Can you add/clarify/correct me on this?

Thanks!

Comment: I think it's because HTML itself is not a language.  HTML5 isn't really either.  It's a combination of JavaScript, HTML, and CSS.  That along with whatever is happening on the server side (PHP, ASP, etc...)  You can't exactly make a specification on something that is more of an amorphous blob than a set of solid rules.

Comment: "HTML5 isn't really either. It's a combination of JavaScript, HTML, and CSS" No HTML is HTML, Javascript is an ECMAScript implementation and CSS is CSS. The reason html5 isn't a spec yet is because the process just takes that long.

Comment: @durbnpoisn HTML is a _markup language_. It may not be advanced like Ruby or Java or whatnot, but it holds a purpose. Not niche enough to be a DSL, but it is the backbone of webpages. JavaScript can insert HTML but it is a language on its own, too, with other applications. (which is why there are so many JS libraries/frameworks out there).

Comment: @PeeHaa Well, HTML 4.01 is not a specification either (even though it's complete). It's still called a recommendation. In the Java world, for example, pretty much all technologies are *specifications*.

Answer (score 4):

HTML5 is a specification - it says so in the first two words of its [abstract](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/#abstract). It's *also* a Recommendation.

HTML5.1 is also a specification. It says so at the start of its abstract too. But it is not a Recommendation, it's a Working Draft, or a "work in progress".

A Recommendation means a recommendation by the W3C - that is, the W3C organisation believes that its contents are sufficiently stable and reliable to *recommend* that you use it to guide you in your work, rather than using its earlier specifications, or other sources when guidance conflicts.

The W3C has no magical powers. There's no W3C police force, and no-one will break down your front door in the dead of night because you've used the `<i>` tag inappropriately. The specification is there to help you, and browser makers, by providing a common set of meanings and behaviours so that web users can all get the most from your content.

Comment: "and no-one will break down your front door in the dead of night because you've used the <i> tag inappropriately" I dare you. I double dare you!